# ¿Estas rutas de un módulo de Laravel están funcionando o no?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, composer

Me encuentro actualizando un proyecto viejo de Laravel (5.5) a la versión 10.x de Laravel.

Este proyecto utiliza "Laravel Modules" cuya documentación oficial se puede leer [aquí](https://laravelmodules.com/docs/v10/helpers)

El proyecto original de laravel tiene un directorio "Modules" con varios modulos (unos 20), cada módulo tiene la siguiente estructura:

```
Modules/ExampleModule:
- start.php
- module.json
- composer.json
- package.json
- webpack-mix.js
- Config/
- Console/
- Database/
- Entities/
- Http/
- Lib/
- Models/
- Providers/
- Resources/
- Tests/
```

Cada módulo tiene rutas propias en `/Http/routes.php` y luego en el fichero anteriormente mencionado (start.php) se hace:

```
if (!app()->routesAreCached()) {
    require __DIR__ . '/Http/routes.php';
}
```

Sin embargo, en el fichero `RouteServiceProviders` del proyecto principal sólo se cargan las rutas que aparecen en `api.php` y en `web.php`. No veo que se estén cargando las rutas de los módulos, también desconozco si se usan o no, y algo que desconozco aún más es "Laravel Modules".

Cuando hago `composer dump-autoload`:

Recibo muchos "Skipping" debido al incumplimiento de psr-4 ¿Esto puede afectar a que no se carguen las rutas?

Ejemplo:

```
Class App\Models\ExampleController located in C:/proyectos/MI_PROYECTO/app\Models\ExampleController.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading 
standard. Skipping.
```

- Lo que sí he notado es que hay funcionalidades en el proyecto principal que utilizan funcionalidades de los módulos, pero lo que aún no sé es si las rutas propias de los módulos se usan o no. En caso de que sí se usen ¿Cómo se llamarían? ¿Igual que una ruta principal o hay que especificar el nombre del módulo en la URL?